# How does typedefing influence compile/assembly?

Tags: c, typedef, ctags

Since there are two ways of writing enums, structs, unions or types where one uses typedef, or alternatively doesn't, I was wondering what would be the benefits and disadvantages of each approach.

```
E.g. 1: typedef enum { ENUM_A, ENUM_B } ENUM_OBJECT;
E.g. 2: typedef unsigned char uint8
```

Personally I like encapsulation provided by the second variant, but when I write code for all enums, structs and unions I would always avoid writing the first example with typedef, but I would use this approach:

```
E.g. 1: enum ENUM_TAG { ENUM_A, ENUM_B };
        enum ENUM_TAG some_variable;
```

Yes, I know that it can take a bit more horizontal space, but to me it better details idea of what is the type than something like this:

```
typedef int matrix_buffer_t[2][5];
matrix_buffer_t some_variable;
```

Can someone outline facts (not personal opinions, since these are discussible) about differences between usage of typedef and no typedef? How does this influence compiled code, program memory size, etc?

I've tried looking at the assembly diff when I compile the following code with no typedef:

```
struct TestStruct
{
    int field;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct TestStruct test;
    printf ("%d\n",  test.field);

    return 1;
}
```

vs code with typedef:

```
typedef struct
{
    int field;
} TestStruct;

int main(void)
{
    TestStruct test;
    printf ("%d\n",  test.field);

    return 1;
}
```

Assembly is definitely not the same. I'm giving a side to side comparison:

```
 ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________
.LC0:                                                                .LC0:
    .string "%d\n"                                                       .string "%d\n"
 main:                                                                main:
    pushq   %rbp                                                          push    rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp                                                    mov     rbp, rsp
    subq    $16, %rsp                                                     sub     rsp, 16
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax                                                mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    movl    %eax, %esi                                                    mov     esi, eax
    movl    $.LC0, %edi                                                   mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    movl    $0, %eax                                                      mov     eax, 0
    call    printf                                                        call    printf
    movl    $1, %eax                                                      mov     eax, 1
    leave                                                                 leave
    ret                                                                   ret
```

It was compiled using godbolt and gcc compiler. For sure I can see the difference I am just wondering when it is better to use which approach depending on benefits/flaws.

Note: I've tried compiling to a .map file which gives addresses of each variable, size, types, etc. and when typedef is used, .map file becomes more compex.

Comment: With `typedef` you create an alias of another type. Using the alias should just like using the original type, there should be no difference at all.

Comment: Can't reproduce, [I get the same assembly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xrn1da9vo).

Comment: What kind of C compiler are you using ? There is no reasonable good reason it would generate defferent assembly for your 2 versions of that code.

Comment: godbolt.org, x86-64 gcc 1.27

Comment: There is no optimisation included.

Comment: There's no such version on godbolt.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There is a x86 gcc 1.27 (for C only). That version is from 1988 according to https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html.

Comment: @Amaterastis: Why would you chose such an old version? Also, I don't see a difference in the assembly you posted. You just showed in once in intel assembly syntax and once in at&t syntax.

Comment: I don't believe there are any x86 ports for gcc that old. It predates the Linux OS and no gcc ports to Windows existed that early.

Comment: Since you ask for measurable values, you can do this yourself. You might want to conduct an experiment with a non-trivial application. From my rudimentary knowledge on compiler construction, I would expect that the resulting machine code is identical.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Both gcc 11.2.0 and MSVC 19.29.30037 produce identical assembly outputs. No extra compiler option given. Just `gcc test.c -S` and `cl test.c /FA`.

Comment: @Lundin It seems to be the first version supporting i386 and needs only a small patch to make it work on modern Linux: https://miyuki.github.io/2017/10/04/gcc-archaeology-1.html

Comment: @user17732522 Out of curiousity, any idea why they made a port to 386 back then? For MS DOS programming?

Comment: @Lundin I have no idea about that. I have not been around at the time. I was just curious and found the article.

Comment: @user17732522 It's before my time as well :) The article suggests this was for an IBM port of Unix called IBM AIX/386. I didn't know that IBM did Unix ports for 386 in parallel to using MS DOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Typedef` is the only feature that makes C language grammar a [`context-sensitive grammar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar).

Its effect is to change the environment of the parser, to convert some symbols into special symbols.

Without `typedef` a parser for the C language would not need an environmental structure to keep track of the definitions of type symbols.

Note that in *ISO/IEC 9899:1999* `5.1.1.2 Translation phases`, typedef acts into the 7th step (the syntax analyser step):

7. White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant. Each
   preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens are
   ***syntactically*** and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.

Comment: How did you come to these conclusions? The C rules for namespaces and identifier naming aren't exclusive for `typedef` identifiers.

Comment: @Lundin You mix the things. namespaces and identifier naming analysis happens much after the syntactical analysis.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone outline facts (not personal opinions, since these are discussible) about differences between usage of typedef and no typedef?

This is the very same, mostly subjective discussion as whether you should `typedef struct` or not. Most people use `typedef`, except the Linux world which tends to type out `struct tag` and there is no obvious right or wrong.

(Although the attempt to provide a rationale for using the latter style in the unprofessional document *Linux kernel coding style* is laughable, entirely subjective and similar to the arguments for using "Hungarian notation".)

Regarding `enum`, you typically use the `typedef` just to not having to type out the `enum tag` every time you use it. Anonymous `enum` without a name are typically just use when dealing with a local, encapsulated type.

There are a few non-subjective reasons why typing out keyword + tag is bad:

- Two preprocessor tokens instead of one can be problematic to use when passing types to function-like macros, using them in X-macros and similar. Example:

  ```
    #define SUPPORTED_TYPES(X) \
      X(int)                   \
      X(float)                 \
      X(struct foo)            \

    enum
    {
      #define ENUM_CONSTANT(type) type ## _val,
      SUPPORTED_TYPES(ENUM_CONSTANT)
    };
  ```

  This code is attempting to create a number of constants corresponding to a list of supported types. It will create `int_val`, `float_val` and then fail upon `struct foo_val` because there are two preprocessor tokens in that type and spaces can't be used in identifiers. On the other hand, the same problem exists when using `unsigned int`.
- Not typing out the tag is consistent with C++ coding style. C++ doesn't have tags in the same manner as C, but the name of the type is the type - with no need to type out the keyword explicitly.

---

Regarding `typedef unsigned char uint8` specifically, this is very bad practice but not because of the `typedef` but because you are inventing your own "local garage standard" instead of using standard C `stdint.h` types.

---

> I've tried looking at the assembly diff when I compile the following code with no typedef

You are doing something wrong, like not using the same optimizer settings or forgetting `#include <stdio.h>` in C90 mode. There's identical machine code, see for yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/zd5q7Pc77